# Unwanted delay in transition for max-height property

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, delay

The following is an expandable container.

```css
* {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  --transition-time: 5s;
}
.collapsible-container {
  --show-more-text: "Show more";
}
.collapsible-container > label::after {
  content: var(--show-more-text);
}
.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height var(--transition-time) linear;
}
.collapsible-container > input + label + .collapsible-content {
}
.collapsible-container > input:checked + label + .collapsible-content {
  transition: max-height var(--transition-time) linear;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible-container" style="border: 2px solid white;">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" name="show more" id="collapsible"/>
  <label for="collapsible"></label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <h1>Collapsible content</h1>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Text that follows</h1>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

It works mostly as I expect it to, except that something is not quite right with the transition.

Whereas here, on stackoverflow, it seems to behave well, when I actually open the page in a browser, a see a strange behavior: if I let the box expand completely, then I observe a substational delay in the non-collapsed-to-collapsed transtion, as per the GIF below.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

[image]

Comment: you cannot see it but you need to wait until the max-height go from 100vh (a very big value) until 0. Do the same with height and you can see it

Comment: _“Unwanted delay”, “something is not quite right with the transition”_ — Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules reveal? Please use the tools to test your assumptions and doubts.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I see, I tried out and verified. What way do I have around it? If I use `100%` I get the same behavior. If I use `fit-content` instead of `100vh` the transition is removed.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yes, I've verified that the computed `max-height` is around the hight of the window.